# importing library in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

let's say I want to use util4, I will write down in my java file:

```
import unit4.turtleLib.Turtle;
```

(I got the jar file in the same folder)

I'm running it over visual studio code without maven

(if I would want to install maven I would use a different IDE instead)
and I can't just put the jar file in the same folder it doesn't work that way, what should I do than?.

Answer (score 0):

1.make sure you hava create a folder named `lib` inside your project and add your `.jar` file into it

2.Configure paths in the `.classpath` like :

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/miglayout.jar"/>
```

you could look at the doucument [add jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_adding-external-jar)